# Limit jquery execution (times/time) on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I created a menu that shows its sub-menu on hover using some CSS and jquery. Thing is, it acts a bit funny in case user hovers lots of times on the menu item. This is the URL: http://91.202.168.37/~ibi/, and this is the jquery code (inside document ready):

```
if ($(window).width()>991) //menu script desktop or laptop
  {
  $('#mob-main-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').hover(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).children('a').toggleClass('bold600');
    $(this).children('a').siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  });
  }
  else // menu script touch device
  {
  $('#mob-main-menu > li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(event){
    if ($(this).children('a').siblings('.sub-menu').css('display') == 'none')
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log('hidden');
      }
    $(this).children('a').toggleClass('bold600');
    $(this).children('a').siblings('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
  });
  }
```

I tried to use setTimeout() function but couldn't get it to work. can I limit the code to queue no more than 2 times, no matter how many hovers it counted? and than after x time to set it back to zero? any other idea to make it work better will be happily accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try make animation with .stop() function it clears the animation queue so it should work correctly

```
$(this).children('a').siblings('.sub-menu').stop().slideToggle();
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my friend. Exactly what I needed.